# .NET GridView : Custom paging text

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

EDIT : NEW CODE

```
  <asp:Panel ID="pnl_display_commentaire" runat="server" GroupingText="Commentaires" >


                 <asp:LinkButton ID="btnmakecomment" class="linkhover" Font-Size="11px" runat="server"> Comments </asp:LinkButton>
              <asp:Panel ID="pnlMComment" CssClass="" runat="server" >
                          <div class="commentbox">
                                       <asp:TextBox ID="MakeComments" CssClass="unwatermarkedcomment" runat="server" Width="90%" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                                       <asp:Button ID="btnPost" CssClass="submitButton" Text="Commenter" runat="server" OnClick="btnComment_Click" CommandName="Comment"  CausesValidation="false" UseSubmitBehavior="False"/>
                                    ajaxToolKit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBoxScrapWme" runat="server" TargetControlID="MakeComments"  WatermarkText="Ecrire un commentaire" WatermarkCssClass="watermarked" />
                            </div>
             </asp:Panel>

            <ajaxToolKit:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="cpe1" runat="Server" TargetControlID="pnlMComment"  Collapsed="true" CollapsedText="Ajouter votre commentaire" ExpandedText="" TextLabelID="btnmakecomment"     ExpandControlID="btnmakecomment" CollapseControlID="btnmakecomment" SuppressPostBack="true" />
             <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
             <script type="text/javascript">
                function Move() {
                     var shouldMove = true;

                     setInterval(function () {
                         var previous = $("a:contains('Previous')");

                         if (previous.html() != undefined && shouldMove) {
                             var grid = $("#CommentGridView");
                             $(previous).insertBefore($(grid));
                             shouldMove = false

                         }
                     }, 100);

                     $(document).on('click', "a:contains('Next')", function () {
                         shouldMove = true;

                     });

                     $(document).on('click', "a:contains('Previous')", function () {
                         shouldMove = true;
                     });

                 }
</script>

             <asp:UpdatePanel ID="update_panel_comments" runat="server">
                 <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:GridView ID="CommentGridView"
            AutoGenerateColumns="true"
            EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="true"
            EmptyDataText="0 commentaire"
            runat="server"
            ShowHeader="false"
            ShowFooter="true"
            Width="90%"
            AllowPaging="True"
            PageSize="3"
            GridLines="None"
            OnPageIndexChanging="CommentGridView_PageIndexChanging">
            <PagerSettings NextPageText="Next" PreviousPageText="Previous" Mode="NextPrevious" />
        </asp:GridView>
                     </ContentTemplate>
                  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnPost" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
```

Im trying to display the next page link at the bottom of my GridView and data, and the previous link ( if it needs to be display) at the top of my gridview.

How can i achieve this ?

EDIT : 
I tested the JS with console.log() and it enter right but does nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very hard to modify the code that ASP.NET web forms automatically generates for you, that's why a lot of developers prefer ASP.NET MVC. Nevertheless, here's an example that uses very little jQuery to move the *"Previous"* link to the top of the `GridView`:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var shouldMove = true;

            setInterval(function ()
            {
                var previous = $("a:contains('Previous')");

                if (previous.html() != undefined && shouldMove)
                {
                    var grid = $("#CommentGridView");
                    $(previous).insertBefore($(grid));
                    shouldMove = false
                }
            }, 100);

            $(document).on('click', "a:contains('Next')", function () {
                shouldMove = true;
            });

            $(document).on('click', "a:contains('Previous')", function () {
                shouldMove = true;
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:GridView ID="CommentGridView"
                AutoGenerateColumns="true"
                EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="true"
                EmptyDataText="0 commentaire"
                runat="server"
                ShowHeader="false"
                ShowFooter="true"
                Width="90%"
                AllowPaging="True"
                PageSize="3"
                GridLines="None"
                OnPageIndexChanging="CommentGridView_PageIndexChanging">
                <PagerSettings NextPageText="Next" PreviousPageText="Previous" Mode="NextPrevious" />
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Output:**

[image: Changing the location of paging buttons in asp.net gridview]

Comment: My previous link stay in the bottom of my gridview :/ ( It shows the Previous then the Next link in the bottom of my gridview )

Comment: ( My gridView is in an update panel ) I call your function in the event pageindexChanging but it didn't do anything

Comment: Did you change PreviousPageText="Précédents" to PreviousPageText="Previous"?Or change the javascript to be var previous = $("a:contains('Précédents')");

Comment: Nop i just used all your code ! He enter is your js function but don't do anything. ( tested with console.log )

Comment: I know, i said that i used your code and replaced mine. My paper settings are the same, with previous and Next .. But it didn't work either

Comment: Can you maybe zip your code and upload to google docs?Because as you can see from the picture I posted on my side it works just fine so I can't figure out why it's not working for you

Comment: Well obviously nothing happens you called the function Move() and you are not calling it anywhere.It should happen onload.Like i said before copy the code EXACTLY as I have it.It must be  $(function () {

Comment: Okay, the id of my gridview is changed when tested in page. I changed it and it works. ( it adds the name of my asp:contentpanel before the id of the gridview ) . Your code works but only in page 2, in page 3 the previous and next button stay at the bottom ..

Comment: The two buttons reset their positions when i switch to page 3, it works only in page 2 ! ><

Comment: Place breakpoints in the   $(document).on('click' for when Next and Previous get clicked, it seems like they are not firing properly.FIgure out why.Move the javascript to the top of the page maybe.You need to do some trial and error if you don't use the code how I'm showing in the example because for me it works on all the pages

Comment: I made this work, i think that the problem was my updatepanel so in the pageindexchanged of my gridview i called my client with "   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "ResetComment", "    var shouldMove = true;", true); " to force display my paging display. THANKS